# Executing Jenkins job (acceptance tests) when a specific Git repo gets changes

Tags: git, github, jenkins

What is the best approach if I want to execute a Jenkins job (acceptance tests) when a specific Git repo gets changes pushed to it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to write a post commit hook within your git repository. For this create a file named "post-commit” in .git/hooks directory.

within this file you have to trigger your jenkins job.

```
#!/bin/sh
curl -X POST http://localhost:8081/job/job_name/build
```

This will trigger your Jenkins job when there are commits within your git repository.

if you Jenkins is secured, you can modify the curl command by below one.

```
curl --user 'user1:password1' -X POST "http://jenkins.mycompany.com:8080/job/JOB-NUMBER1/build" --data token=mytoken1 --data delay=0sec
```

if your Jenkins is on remote machine, you need to enable **Trigger builds remotely** from **Build Trigger** section.

Comment: Would this plugin work: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin ?

Comment: This one is specifically for github. If you are using github still i doubt this will work. If you are using github then there is another solution i have.

Comment: What is the other solution?

Comment: If you are using github then you can easily configure post webhook.